# setNeedsLayout in UIView subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, setneedsdisplay

I have a `UIViewController` and in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, i am calling `[self view] setNeedsLayout];`

This view call's it's subview's (a `UIScrollView`) `layoutSubviews` method, but the `UIScrollView` doesn't call `layoutSubviews` for it's subviews. Is this how it's suppose to be? I thought if you call `setNeedsLayout` on a view, it will call `layoutSubviews` on each and every subivew and their subviews and on...

Do I have to manually, override `layoutsubview` in `UIScrollView` and call `setNeedsDisplay` for each of the subviews?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I observed the same thing in my app some time ago and it seems that `setNeedsLayout` only affects the view's subviews and does not traverse down. If you use custom views you can easily subclass the views and iterate over the subviews in `setNeedsLayout` and perform an explicit `setNeedsLayout` on them.

If you want it to be the default behavior you could override the method in a category, but I really would not do this since it affects all views and may introduce performance and other unexpected issues.

You could do something like this

```
@interface UIView (Layout)
  
- (void)setNeedsLayoutRecursively;

@end

@implementation UIView (Layout)

- (void)setNeedsLayoutRecursively {
  for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
    [view setNeedsLayoutRecursively];
  }
  [self setNeedsLayout];
}

@end
```

*typed in browser, not tested*

**However, be aware that this is not good practice! You should only update what needs updating. This could result in a severe performance hit. Use with caution!**

Comment: Thanks..I was hoping I didn't have to do that, wanted to avoid that. Don't really want to subview alot of UIViews as I have a deep view hierarchy. Anyways, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: excellent little opt-in codelet that solved my problem perfectly.  thank you!

Comment: But child views shouldn't have to worry about the parent's state. Only if the bounds of the child view changed does the child need to be laid out again. This can happen if the parent's layoutSubviews (or autoresize masks) change the child's size. In that situation, layoutSubviews propagates down the view hierarchy.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick yes, use with caution. Amended the answer.